# Google OAuth optional parameter 'prompt' being overridden in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, oauth, google-oauth, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I have set up Google OAuth Authentication in my Blazor Webassembly application and everything works fine. However, once I've logged in for the first time (by entering my email and password into the google login screen - see below)

Google Login Screen

[image: 1]

If I then log out and sign in again, I'm not required to enter any credentials. I've found this is because **`prompt=none`** is automatically set in the request URL. But, due to specifications of the application, I need the user to be able to select different accounts after they have logged out

So, I added **`prompt=consent`** to my **`Appsettings.Production.Json`**, under additional parameters for **`ProviderOptions`** (see below)

```
"ProviderOptions": {
  "Authority": "https://accounts.google.com/",
  "ClientId": "TEST.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://example.co.uk/authentication/logout-callback",
  "RedirectUri": "https://example.co.uk/authentication/login-callback",
  "ResponseType": "id_token",
  "AdditionalProviderParameters": {
    "prompt": "consent"
    }
}
```

And these values are assigned in Program.cs using the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("ProviderOptions", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
});
```

I thought this would then replace the **`prompt=none`** with **`prompt=consent`** in the request URL, but this was not the case. I then got the following error stating there cannot be 2 values for **`prompt`**

Google Multiple Values Error

[image: 2]

No matter what I try I cannot stop the **`prompt=none`** from being added to the Request URL even though I'm specifying **`prompt=consent`**

Has anyone encountered this or know of a solution, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please show all configuration and code as *text* rather than images. It's inherently textual information.

Comment: Ah yes, I've done that now thank you for the heads up

Comment: You code is adding a ClientID and so is the callback giving the error message two parameters.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The error is 2 parameters from 'prompt' not 'ClientID'